# Node require() issue with 2 scripts that require each other

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 different node scripts... `save_info.js` imports `openConections array` from `sse_server.js`. And, `sse_server.js` imports `function broadcast` from `save_info.js`.
However, this is causing `openConnections array` to be `undefined` inside of `save_info.js`. Why is this and how can I fix this?

save_info.js:

```
var openConnections = require('../scripts/sse_server.js').openConnections;

function broadcast(result, event, httpObject) { 
    var result = JSON.stringify(result);
    var date = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    httpObject.write('id: ' + date + '\n');
    httpObject.write('data: { \"' + event + '\":\n');
    httpObject.write('data:' + result + '\n');
    httpObject.write('data: }' + '\n\n');
}

 function db_finish(err, product, numberAffected, 
                   result, event) {
    if (err) { console.log(err) }
    else { 
        console.log("Db insert successfull");
        openConnections.forEach(function(httpObject) {
            broadcast(result, event, httpObject);
        });
    }
    console.log("Numer effected " + numberAffected);
}
module.exports.openConnections = openConnections;
```

sse_server.js:

```
var broadcast = require("../data/save_info").broadcast; 

var openConnections = []; 

    for (var model in models){
        models[model].find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1).exec(
            function (err, result){
                broadcast(result, model, res);
            });
    }
 module.exports.broadcast = broadcast;
```

Comment: running require on these files mutually will make them be executed each twice. That means that a loads b, and b loads a, then uses a... but a has no definition of b because the instance of a being used is not the first one.

Comment: Related question, what's the typical approach for handling cyclic dependencies in interpreted languages? The best I can come up with is a C-style "header" with "prototypes" that gets "linked" at some point after it's parsed. Something like lazy-require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent circular dependency, nodejs module loader stops loading sse_server module in save_info.js  That's why openConnections is undefined.  To resolve this, do the following:

1) Move broadcast() out into a separate module (broadcast.js for example).

2) put require('../data/broadcast.js') in both sse_server.js and save_info.js

3) Remove require('../data/save_info') in sse_server.js

Comment: I was hoping there was a work around instead of this...but good enough. I thought node somehow handled circle dependencies so they wouldn't happen.

Comment: module loader stops loading to prevent circular dependencies so not much we can do but to prevent it.  I guess that's the work around.  I wish node gives some warnings that there is a circular dependency and says it's not loading the module so that we don't have to go through the debugger and try to figure out why our codes are not working though.